# Resize Popup to Content - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm trying to create this floating modal popup that sits in the top right-hand corner of the screen. I want the background to be active (as in I can do things normally on the webpage without the popup bothering it.

The problem arises when I want to resize the modal to the content on the inside. So for example, if I were to write a paragraph inside that popup, it would automatically resize the modal to contain that text. Preferably I want the width to be constant but I want it to extend downward depending on the text.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
            /* The Modal (background) */
            .modal {
                display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 50%; /* Full width */
                height: 50px; /* Full height */
                overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
            }

            /* Modal Content */
            .modal-content {
                background-color: orange;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                border: 1px solid #888;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: auto;
            }

            /* The Close Button */
            .close {
                color: #aaaaaa;
                float: right;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

                .close:hover,
                .close:focus {
                    color: #000;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Modal Example</h2>

        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So when the "modal-content" div increases in size due to text, I want the parent div (myModal) to adjust its size accordingly. I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `overflow:auto` so the scrollbar will not appear when there's a long text. The modal expands automatically and has a minimum height of 100 pixels.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "inline-block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  /* Full width */
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.modal-content {
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus nunc, rhoncus in pellentesque vitae, bibendum vitae nunc. Morbi a arcu blandit, maximus tortor rhoncus, commodo libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus egestas odio mauris, eu imperdiet ligula lobortis malesuada. Cras sit amet laoreet odio. Vivamus feugiat tortor a ullamcorper pulvinar. Mauris vestibulum semper ex nec pretium. Curabitur in elementum leo, et mollis dui. Integer convallis scelerisque metus, vel pulvinar metus sollicitudin eu. Nunc eu tristique odio.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove position absolute from modal content and add some padding

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>  Modal Content </title>
    <style>
        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 50%; /* Full width */
            height: auto; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */

        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: orange;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            margin: auto;
            padding:20px;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Modal Example</h2>

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>

    </div>



    <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "inline-block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```